# Job criado no SSIS não funciona no SQL SERVER AGENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-access, odbc, ssis

Tenho um job criado no SSIS (funcionando perfeitamente) que não funciona no SQL SERVER AGENT. O job extrai alguns dados de uma tabela do access, via ODBC, e carrega em uma tabela do local do sql server. O Sql Server e a base de dados do access estão em servidores diferentes, ambos com estrutura x86. Coloquei tanto o job no SQL Server quanto na configuração do SSIS para rodar em x86, mas continuo não conseguindo rodar o job no Sql Server Agent.

Abaixo o erro apresentado:

> 01/14/2016 12:49:15,carrega_hlr_join_atem,Erro,1,W7RJO071543,carrega_hlr_join_atem,Exec Package,,Executado como usuário: EMBRATEL\EGSANTO. Utilitário de Execução de Pacotes do Microsoft (R) SQL Server  Versão 11.0.5058.0 para 32 bits  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.    Início: 12:49:15  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.12     Código: 0xC0014020     Origem: Package Gerenciador de conexões "TB_HLR"     Descrição: Erro de ODBC -1.  Fim do Erro  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Código: 0xC0014009     Origem: Package Gerenciador de conexões "TB_HLR"     Descrição: Erro ao tentar estabelecer uma conexão ODBC com o servidor de banco de dados.  Fim do Erro  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Código: 0x0000020F     Origem: Tarefa Fluxo de Dados NeFone (Access) [67]     Descrição: Falha na chamada do método AcquireConnection para o gerenciador de conexões TB_HLR com o código de erro 0xC0014009. Talvez haja mensagens de erro postadas antes desta com mais informações sobre o motivo da falha na chamada de método AcquireConnection.  Fim do Erro  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Código: 0xC0047017     Origem: Tarefa Fluxo de Dados SSIS.Pipeline     Descrição: Falha na validação de NeFone (Access) com o código de erro 0x80004005.  Fim do Erro  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Código: 0xC004700C     Origem: Tarefa Fluxo de Dados SSIS.Pipeline     Descrição: Falha na validação de um ou mais componentes.  Fim do Erro  Erro: 2016-01-14 13:06:34.13     Código: 0xC0024107     Origem: Tarefa Fluxo de Dados      Descrição: Houve erros durante a validação da tarefa.  Fim do Erro  DTExec: a execução do pacote retornou DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Início: 12:49:15  Conclusão: 13:06:34  Tempo decorrido:  1038.37 segundos.  Falha na execução do pacote.  A etapa falhou.,00:17:19,0,0,,,,0

Poderiam, por gentileza, me ajudar com este problema?

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escrevi o mesmo indicado no comentário do Rodrigão na sua pergunta do stackoverflow.com.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794737/2788478

Comment: André eu configurei um ODBC de acesso na máquina e no SSIS utilizei uma caixa de origem ODBC com essa configuração criada atrelada. Foi isso que vc quis dizer no meu post do stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Você fez isso como administrador e criou uma entrada de sistema ou de usuário?

Comment: Fiz como adm e criei uma entrada de sistema.

Comment: Sua mensagem tem: " Talvez haja mensagens de erro postadas antes desta com mais informações sobre o motivo da falha na chamada de método AcquireConnection." Dá uma olhada no Event Viewer e observa se tem algum erro que ocorra antes que pode nos ajudar nisso.

Comment: Obrigado André, fiz o que você falou na minha pergunta no stackoverflow.com de usar o ADO e funcionou.

Comment: Que bom, @rcockell, fico feliz.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você executa ele pelo Visual Studio ele funciona correto? 
Caso sim, é provável que ele não tenha o driver versão 64 bits do access instalado no servidor.
(esse é do 2010, baixe o correspondente da sua versão do access).
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Verifique se os drivers 64 bits estão instalados. Caso não dê pra verificar ou vc não tenha acesso pra mexer nisso, tente rodar o job marcando a opção "32-bit-runtime" na aba "Configuration/Advanced" do JOB no SQL Agent.

Comment: Mas eu preciso do driver de 64 bits mesmo sendo ambos os ambientes 32 bits? Eu já rodo o job com essa configuração marcada! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Cara, o job que você roda é no servidor ? ou é na própria maquina de desenvolvimento ?

Comment: São dois "deskservers"! Um está com o SSIS e o SQL SERVER AGENT e outro está com a base de dados do Access...